# The type or namespace name 'Editor' does not exist in the namespace 'Firebase.Unity'

Tags: unity3d-android, firebase-database

Скачал Unity SDK Firebase. Распаковал в Unity. Когда в скрипте начал подключать библиотеки:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using Firebase.Unity;
using Firebase.Database;
using Firebase.Unity.Editor; #ИЗ-ЗА ЭТОЙ СТРОКИ ОШИБКА
```

то Unity начала ругаться на эту строку, вот так:
*error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Editor' does not exist in the namespace 'Firebase.Unity' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*

Не знаю, в чём дело, может, кто-нибудь поможет?